# to overshadow in japanese

Tags: words

As the title say, I want to express the idea of an character overshadowing the main character in a story. The only thing that I was able to found in the dictionary was 霞む, but this seems to be more on the sense of "cast a shadow over" when what I'm looking for is "much more prominent or important than". What could I use in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

霞む has that sense, though relationship is reverse. In short, 主役{しゅやく}が霞む{かすむ} means that the main character is overshadowed by another character.

If you want the subject to be the one who overshadows, you can say ◯◯が 主役を食う{くう} or use counterparts of to surpass or to overwhelm（凌駕{りょうが}する・圧倒{あっとう}する）. (You should be careful that aspect of these verbs is ている form when it's needed)